# c# date methods not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have created a Date program which should return the user the date when inputted. I have not been using DateTime, as I wanted to create my own Date class instead. For some reason within my if statements my value does not seem to be working within my main for some reason. Is there any way around this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy");

            int day;
            int month;
            int year;

            string[] read = Console.ReadLine().Split('/');
            day = int.Parse(read[0]);
            month = int.Parse(read[1]);
            year = int.Parse(read[2]);

            Date i = new Date(day, month, year);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", i.day, i.month, i.year);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Date
        {
            public int month; // 1-12
            public int day; // 1-31 depending on month
            public int year
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }

            public Date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                this.day = day;
                this.month = month;
                this.year = year;
            }

            public int Year
            {
                get { return year; }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                        month = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", value, "year out of range");
                }
            }

            private int Month
            {
                get { return month; }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                        month = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
                }
            }

            public int Day
            {
                get { return day; }
                set
                {

                    int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                    if (value > 0 && value <= days[month])
                        day = value;

                    else if (month == 2 && value == 29 &&
                        year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
                        day = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("days", value, "day is out of range");

                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(str, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`? If you really need your `Date` type(what is it's benefit?) you can use `new Date(dt.Day, dt.Month, dt.Year)`

Comment: What does _"within my if statements my value does not seem to be working within my main for some reason"_ mean **exactly**? Explain what you expect to see, what you actually see and where exactly that occurs.

Comment: You have a property Year (capital y) that uses the property year (lower case y) and accepts a value between 1 and 12. There is room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You are using member variables, not properties as you intended

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", i.Day, i.Month, i.Year);
```

changed the `.day` to `.Day`

Refactored your code a little bit. This way, it will do all the validations when you try setting the values. Setters can be made private, as you might only allow the user to set thing via constructor.

```
    class Date
    {
        private int _month; // 1-12
        private int _day; // 1-31 depending on month
        private int _year;

        public Date(int day, int month, int year)
        {
            Day = day;
            Month = month;
            Year = year;
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set
            {

                _year = value;
                //Do you checks and throw exception as needed
                //throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", value, "year out of range");
            }
        }

        public int Month
        {
            get { return _month; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                    _month = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
            }
        }

        public int Day
        {
            get { return _day; }
            set
            {

                int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                if (value > 0 && value <= days[_month])
                    _day = value;

                else if (_month == 2 && value == 29 &&
                    _year % 400 == 0 || (_year % 4 == 0 && _year % 100 != 0))
                    _day = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, "Day is out of range");

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me... whenever I enter a date even something which is valid it always goes to the last Argument Out Of Range which is within the last method named "Day".

Comment: @ramteen1993 What values are you entering?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation enough to comment. So I answer: Lacked the leap year in your date class.

Answer (score 0):

Besides learning a new language there is no reason in C# to reinvent new Date classes. 
It is one of the biggest mistakes coming from the C++ ages before an official string type was there. Everybody had its own string class. We have now about 6 in our software with code to convert between all of them.
So my advise: Don't do this and instead try to read the documentation because most of the functionality is there. If it isn't there, please create extension methods and at last resort derive oder embed the existing class.